# How to show standard error with curve_fit from scipy in python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, exponential

I am trying to fit multiple curve equations to my data to determine what kind of decay curve best represents my data. I am using the `curve_fit` function within `scipy` in python.

Here is my example data:

```
data = {'X':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12 ,13 ,14 ,15
],
        'Y':[55, 55, 55, 54, 54, 54, 54, 53, 53, 50, 45, 37, 27, 16, 0
]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I then want to try fitting a linear, logarithmic, second-degree polynomial, and exponential decay curve to my data points and then plotting. I am trying out the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import array, exp
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load the dataset
data = df.values
# choose the input and output variables
x, y = data[:, 0], data[:, 1]

def func1(x, a, b):
    return a * x + b

def func2(x, a, b):
    return a * np.log(x) + b

def func3(x, a, b, c):
    return a*x**2+b*x+c

def func4(x, a, b, c):
    return a*exp(b*x)+c

params, covs = curve_fit(func1, x, y)

params, _ = curve_fit(func1, x, y)
a, b = params[0], params[1]
yfit1 = a * x + b
print('Linear decay fit:')
print('y = %.5f * x + %.5f' % (a, b))

params, _  = curve_fit(func2, x, y)
a, b = params[0], params[1]
yfit2 = a * np.log(x) + b
print('Logarithmic decay fit:')
print('y = %.5f * ln(x)+ %.5f' % (a, b))

params, _ = curve_fit(func3, x, y)
a, b, c = params[0], params[1], params[2]
yfit3 = a*x**2+b*x+c
print('Polynomial decay fit:')
print('y = %.5f * x^2 + %.5f * x + %.5f' % (a, b, c))

params, _  = curve_fit(func4, x, y)
a, b, c = params[0], params[1], params[2]
yfit4 = a*exp(x*b)+c
print('Exponential decay fit:')
print('y = %.5f * exp(x*%.5f)+%.5f' % (a, b, c))

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', label="y-original")
plt.plot(x, yfit1, label="y=a * x + b")
plt.plot(x, yfit2, label="y=a * np.log(x) + b")
plt.plot(x, yfit3, label="y=a*x^2 + bx + c")
plt.plot(x, yfit4, label="y=a*exp(x*b)+c")
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend(loc='best', fancybox=True, shadow=True)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

This produces the following text and visual plotting output:
[image]

I had originally tried to find a way to show the r-squared value for each curve fit, but I found out that for non-linear curves, R squared is not suitable, and that instead I should be identifying the standard error for each curve fit to best judge which curve equation best describes the decay I am seeing in my datapoints. My question is how can I take my code and the fits of each equation I attempted and output a standard error reading for each curve fit so that I can best judge which equation most accurately represents my data? I am ultimately trying to make the judgement call of saying "I have discovered that as the x-axis value increases, the y-axis value decays ..." and fitting in that blank with "linearly", "logarithmically", second-degree quadratically", or "exponentially". Visually I see that the exponentially decay equation fits my data the best, but I do not have a quantitative basis to make that call, other than simply visually, and so that is why I am trying to find out how I can print the standard error, so that I can judge the best fit for an equation as corresponding to the equation with the lowest standard error. I have been unable to locate just how to derive this from my calculations from documentation.

Comment: A simple check for the [goodness of fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit) is the [reduced chi-square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_chi-squared_statistic)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mean Absolute Scaled Error ([MASE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_scaled_error)) for comparing the goodness of fit. Define a function for MASE as follows:

```python
import numpy as np

def mase(actual : np.ndarray, predicted : np.ndarray):

    forecast_error = np.mean(np.abs(actual - predicted))
    naive_forecast = np.mean(np.abs(np.diff(actual)))
    mase = forecast_error / naive_forecast

    return mase
```

Then simply compare all of the predicted values with the actual values (both must be NumPy arrays to use the function above). You can then select the model/equation with the lowest MASE value. For example:

```python
>>> actual = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> predicted1 = np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3])
>>> mase(actual, predicted1)
0.20000000000000004
>>>
>>> predicted2 = np.array([1.1, 2.1, 3.1])
>>> mase(actual, predicted2)
0.10000000000000009
```

Here we can safely say that `predicted2` has a lower MASE value and thus is favorable.